# Using custom view xib in a view controller xib

Tags: xcode4

Is it possible to create a custom view XIB and in turn use that in a view controller XIB (and have its visual appearance show up as well)?

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I am aware. I have been making placeholder container `UIView`'s and programmatically adding the sub view controller's view in `viewDidLoad`